# template for a view?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I created a view which is viewable at `http://mysite.com/branch-locator`.   The view is being displayed by my page.tpl.php.  How do I override this and use a new template file called branchlocator.tpl.php to display my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How specific do you need to be with the name of your template file? You should be able to create a page--branch-locator.tpl.php that gets picked up by Drupal's auto-detection mechanism. At least, that would have worked in D6 (minus the extra hyphen after page).

Comment: oh cool, i was doing views--branch-locator.tpl.php

Comment: this use of the page-- naming convention uses the path alias, so if your path to the view changes, you'll need to update the tpl file.